# Does HTC Desire 816 Dual sim have NFC?

Tags: nfc, htc-desire-816-dual

I decided to buy HTC Desire 816 and in my country ( Egypt ) only the dual sim version is avaliable !

I heared that that version is *not able to have NFC* option :-( is that true ??

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the dual sim version does NOT have NFC. The [spec sheet](http://www.htc.com/hk-en/smartphones/htc-desire-816/#/) explicitly states that NFC is only included in the 4G LTE model and not the dual sim one.

Connectivity:

```
Wi-Fi                                Yes
Wi-Fi standards supported            802.11 b/ g/ n
GPS                                  Yes
Bluetooth                            Yes, v 4.00
NFC                                  No
Infrared                             No
DLNA                                 Yes
Wi-Fi Direct                         No
MHL Out                              No
HDMI                                 No
Headphones                           3.5mm
FM                                   Yes
USB                                  Micro-USB
Charging via Micro-USB               Yes
Proprietary charging connector       No
Proprietary data connector           No
Number of SIMs                       2
SIM 1    
SIM Type                             Nano-SIM
GSM/ CDMA                            GSM
3G                                   Yes
SIM 2    
SIM Type                             Nano-SIM
GSM/ CDMA                            GSM
3G                                   No
```

Comment: thanx .. and does it have wifi-direct or any way to transfer data quicker than bluetooth ??

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMostafa, no it doesn't have WiFi-direct either, I updated the answer with all available connectivity options. Bluetooth or regular WiFi using a hotspot are your best options. You can turn the HTC Desire into a hotspot itself and let other phones connect to transfer files.